# Hide UIBarButtonItem only while a task is performing

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation bar with a refresh rightBarButtonItem and I want to hide it while the refresh is happening.

I tried setting it to nil and then set it back to the refresh button after the task was complete but the task is probably too fast so it doesn't show.

Any other way to hide it?

I want to give the user a feedback that the refresh button was tapped aside from the MBProgressHUD that I'm using.

Comment: Is it possible for the task to take time or do you just want the button to have a quick flash effect?

Comment: I want the task to be as fast as possible (it's parsing data from a website). A quick flash effect will do it.

Comment: The selected solution here might help, it will need some modification most likely though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893181/how-to-flash-a-button-on-ui-thread/6902517#6902517

Comment: The problem is that a UIBarButtonItem has no setAlpha property.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not to remove it, but rather disable it which will 'grey' it out.

Use this code:

`rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;` or `[rightBarButtonItem setEnabled: NO];` depending on your syntax choice.

You will first need to have a reference for the rightBarButtonItem, this can be achieved by using an IBOutlet.

Comment: I tried adding IBOutlet for a UIBarButtonItem in my header file and then in the method that is called by the refresh button, I set it to enabled = NO and when the task is completed I set it back to YES, still no feedback. any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Is your task running on the main thread or a background thread? If it's the main thread, you're probably blocking the UI. By the time the UI's able to update, you've already reset enabled to YES.

Comment: It's on the main thread and I am blocking the UI. Any way around that? (I want the UI to stay blocked while the task is running)

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the UIBarButtonItem before you start blocking the thread. If you can't solve it, upload the code in question to Github's gist.